# Updating Multiple Records with varying conditions in a single query

Tags: javascript, postgresql, nestjs, typeorm, query-builder

With Typeorm + NestJS + Postgres is there a way to update multiple records with varying conditions and varying values in a single query. Normally I could do

```
await getConnection()
  .createQueryBuilder()
  .update(Entity)
  .set({ columnName: "newValue" })
  .where({ id: In(1,2,3,4,5,6) })
  .execute();
```

and this will update all entries with the specified ID. But in the case of having the following data structure

```
const array = [{id: 1, value: 'New Value For Record 1'},..., {id: 1000, value: 'New Value For Record 1000'}]
```

I could use for loop to update each single entry as below:

```
array1.forEach(rec => {
  usersRepo.update(
     { id: rec.id },
     {
        columnName: rec.value
     }
  );
})
```

but this does not seem to be efficient and won't give good performance. Is there a way to do achieve multiple update on varying conditions with query builder.

Comment: As far as I know, currently this is not possible. See [this issue](https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/issues/7326).

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve that we two queries

1. Get all the rows you need, basically a find would be enough, like this.
2. after that map the results array to do your changes
3. Last thing to do is to use save method, from Typeorm docs:

> save - Saves a given entity or array of entities. If the entity already exists in the database, then it's updated. If the entity does not exist in the database yet, it's inserted.

```
const array = await yourRepo.find()
const newArr = array.map(el=> ({...el, value: 'New Value For Record'+el.id})
await yourRepo.save(newArr)
```

Cheers.